# How to use radio buttons to calculate output of highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

What I am trying to do is find a way so that when a radio button is checked, the value assigned to it can be used in the calculations of the chart, and updates it instantly (just like the sliders do). I think im on the right path... here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nlem33/ZhER3/

```
var selected = 1;
$(document).ready(function(event) {
    $("input[name=chooseProduct]").change(function(){
        selected = $(this).val();
    });
```

Comment: When I did a `console.log($(this).val());` and selected option 2, it printed out 230, which was the correct value.  So is that not what you want?

Comment: If you look at line 104 "newdata.push(selected * units * i);" I want the variable called "selected" to update the graph based on which button is selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your change function can call the sliderHandler function directly, although it needs a slight modification to work when called this way:

```
      $("input[name=chooseProduct]").change(function(){
        selected = $(this).val();
        sliderHandler();
    });
```

and the sliderHandler needs this:

```
 if (this.id === 'slider1') {
        $('#slider1_value').html(ui.value);
        units = ui.value;
    } else if (this.id === 'slider2') {
        $('#slider2_value').html('$' + ui.value);
        price = ui.value;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L5cY6/

Comment: One more quick thing, how can I make the chart run the calculation of the checked (default) button when the page is loaded rather then when you select another box?

Comment: Just call sliderHandler(); on page load

Comment: hmmm when I do that it breaks the application and loads the default highchart area chart instead of mine